# Lower bound on right tail probability given the expectation

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm reading the book "The Probabilistic Method" (for discrete mathematics) by Alon and Spencer, and I'm having trouble deciphering the following implication from the proof of Theorem 1.5.1.

[Link to the key part of the proof.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMqsw.jpg)

Here, I will *try* to provide what I think is the minimal amount of detail required. If more details is needed, I apologize, but please ask me!

Let $Y$ be a discrete random variable taking on values $0,1,\dots,m$ such that its expectation satisfies the lower bound:
$$ \mathbb{E}(Y)\geq 2\cdot m^{1-t\delta^2/2} $$
I would like to conclude, using the fact that $Y\leq m$, that:
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y\geq m^{1-t\delta^2/2})\geq m^{-t\delta^2/2} $$

I have spent a long time staring at it, and cannot seem to find why this is true. I have a feeling that I'm missing something very small.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result follows directly from the reverse Markov inequality. Reverse Markov Inequality states that for a random variable $Y$ that is upper bounded by $m$, we have that $\Pr(Y \leq a) \leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[m - Y]}{m - a}$. (It is essentially the Markov inequality applied to $m - Y$).Applying the above inequality for $a = m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}$, we get $\displaystyle \Pr(Y \leq m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}) \leq \dfrac{m - \mathbb{E}[Y]}{m - m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}} $. Therefore, we have,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(Y \geq m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}) &\geq 1 - \dfrac{m - \mathbb{E}[Y]}{m - m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}} \\
&\geq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[Y] - m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}}{m - m^{1 - t\delta^2/2}}\\
&\geq m^{-t\delta^2/2}
\end{align*}